# Seeking specific Massachusetts family history book?

Tags: united-states, massachusetts, books

I am looking to obtain a specific reference book, "The descendants of William Story: Who came to Ipswich, Massachusetts in 1637 : the first eight generations" that was written by Robert L. Pratt in 2000.  I know it's available on [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/title/descendants-of-william-story-who-came-to-ipswich-massachusetts-in-1637-the-first-eight-generations/oclc/45199386) for research but I'm hoping to get the physical book in my hands.

Where can it be found?

Comment: I would like to second, in general, @shoover 's comment about the Internet Archive. Whenever I find a reference to some old family history book (I know, this one isn't old, but still), I head over to archive.org to see if they have a copy. Frequently, they *do*, and then, so do I. They have PDF, text and ePub downloads.

Answer (score 4):

The description of the book at the website of [Genealogical Publishing Company](http://www.genealogical.com/) (genealogical.com) says :

> The Descendants of William Story of Ipswich, Massachusetts
>
> Robert L. Pratt, M.D.         Format: Hardcover
>       Pages: 540 pp.
>       Published: 2000
>       Price: $43.20
>
> Item #: GWFH237
>
> Send orders to: 3 Piping Rock Circle, Saratoga Springs, NY 12866. The
>   price of the book includes shipping by first-class mail.
>
> The descendants of William Story through eight generations (and more
>   in some cases). Fully referenced. Allied families include Burnham,
>   Low, Foster, Andrews, and others.
>
> This Gateway Press item is only available from the Author.
>   Instructions for the purchase of this product are included in the
>   description above.

If you prefer to look for a second-hand copy, you could try the meta-search engine [Bookfinder.com](https://www.bookfinder.com/). This will give you results from many [partner booksellers and listing services](https://www.bookfinder.com/about/booksellers/) including [AbeBooks](https://www.abebooks.com/) and [Biblio](https://www.biblio.com/).

Answer (score 4):

For other researchers who merely want to do research on William Story and his descendants and are not as particular about having the physical book, a related book by a different author has been digitized and is available for short-term loan at the Internet Archive. That book is [*Descendants of William Story and Sarah Foster of Ipswich, Essex County, Massachusetts*, compiled by Betty Andrews Storey](https://archive.org/details/descendantsofwil00stor/page/n1/mode/2up).

On the title page, Ms. Storey comments:

> The ***Descendants of William Story and Sarah Foster of Ipswich, Essex County, Massachusetts*** is a result of the help of many individuals that I have corresponded with over the years. . . . I have included charts to show my two lines of descent from William Story and Sarah Foster.
>
> I refer to "The Descendants of William Story Who Came to Ipswich, Massachusetts in 1637" by Robert L. Pratt. Published in 2000 by Gateway Press, 1001 N. Calvert Street, Baltimore, MD 21202 in my compilation.

The first half of Ms. Storey's book contains nearly 150 footnotes citing Pratt's book. Ms. Storey's book begins with pedigree charts for her family's ancestry back to William Story and Sarah Foster, but the bulk of the book is a [NGSQ System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genealogical_numbering_systems#NGSQ_System) report of William Story and his descendants.

Ms. Storey provides her contact information (as of April 2004) on the title page.